# Targeting older Windows versions (Windows Server 2008 R2)

Tags: windows, rust

I have an older Windows 10 workstation with Rust `1.37` (`stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc`) and Visual Studio 2017 with the following features:

- Visual C++ Build Tools core features
- VC++ 2017 version 15.9 v14.16 latest v141 tools
- Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable Update
- Windows 10 SDK (10.0.17763.0)
- Visual C++ tools for CMake
- Testing tools core features - Build Tools

On this workstation, I can compile a program that runs fine on my target environment (Windows Server 2008 R2).

I have a newer Windows 10 workstation on which I installed the legacy version of Visual Studio 2017. Interestingly, the installer doesn't offer the exact same options for C++ build tools, but I think I have the necessary ones, e.g.:

- VC++ 2017 version 15.9 v14.16 latest v141 tools
- Visual C++ tools for CMake and Linux
- Windows 10 SDK (10.0.17763.0)

However, when I compile the program (with the same Rust version/toolchain) on this computer, it errors out on my target environment with "The program can't start because VCRUNTIME140.dll is missing from your computer".

What am I missing here? How can I setup rustup/cargo to target my specific environment?

Comment: Looks like you need VC++ 2015 redist aka v140.

Comment: @rustyx, thanks for the suggestion, i'll try that now. Do I need to uninstall the v141 tools? Do I need to reinstall Rust via rustup? Do I need to reinstall rustup?

Comment: I uninstalled `VC++ 2017 version 15.9 v14.16 latest v141 tools` and installed `VC++ 2015.3 v14.00 (v140) toolset for desktop`, then reinstalled rustup AND Rust, then cargo clean and built my project, and am still running into the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I think It’s because of not choosing some components when you install the vs. 
by the way, vs 2015 is not a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out I was wrong: my project was not compiled with `stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc` on my older computer. I had at some point installed the `x86_64-pc-windows-gnu` toolchain and set it as the override for this project. Changing my toolchain to `x86_64-pc-windows-gnu` on the new computer produced a binary that was able to run on the target machine.

Rather than deleting this question, I'll leave it here for others who may need to target older Windows environments:

If you are having problems running a Rust binary on an older Windows computer, try compiling with `x86_64-pc-windows-gnu` rather than `msvc`.